# How many themes have been released by LEGO?

Tags: sets, history

I would like to know the various themes, current & discontinued, that LEGO has released in brick/element form.

Comment: Many bricks/elements are used in multiple themes, do you mean sets?

Comment: Any such list would be constantly out of date.

Comment: @ Z-BD:I was thinking of general themes. Town/city. Castle. Space. etc. A set count would be gigantic.

Comment: @ Joe: As of 1/5/2012

Comment: But it's nearly 1/6/2012! Why would I want your old list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In much the same way we had with the [question on categorising bricks](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/214/how-are-lego-bricks-categorized), I think this is something better handled by other sites out there:

- [BrickLink's list of Set Categories](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=S), or from their [main catalogue page](http://www.bricklink.com/catalog.asp) you can see a dropdown with themes listed.
- [Peeron's Theme Tree starts here](http://www.peeron.com/inv/theme), with the core [LEGO System themes starting here](http://peeron.com/inv/theme/LEGO/SYSTEM).
- [BrickSet also has a list of themes](http://brickset.com/browse/), as well as the [Theme Browser](http://brickset.com/browse/themes/) which lists the most popular on the page, and the complete set in a dropdown.

Comment: Since there should be a concrete answer to this LEGO question, this seems the perfect site to seek the answer.

Comment: That's what I thought about the categories one as well, but I was out voted ;)

Comment: Thanks! I checked all of your suggested links. I liked Bricksets theme browser best. It is an eye opener. I knew there were more themes than I could bring to mind, but I had no idea there would be so many.

Comment: The count hovers right around 90 themes. I would have guessed 50.

Comment: @MajorStackings Don't forget that some themes also have sub-themes: http://brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Alpha%20Team lists two proper sub themes for Alpha Team, and City has around 13 core sub-themes, like Police, Fire, Space, Trains, etc. which you can see in the right hand column.